# Recursive factorial subroutine in x64 assembly gives stack overflow

Tags: assembly, recursion, 64-bit, x86-64, att

I am implementing a recursive algorithm to calculate the factorial of a given number in x64 assembly. (I am using the AT&T syntax.)

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
int factorial(int x){
    if(x == 1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return x*factorial(x-1);
    }
 }
```

Now, my implementation in x64 assembly:

```
factorial:  
    #Start of subroutine
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp 

    cmpq $1, %rdi   #If rdi == 1, return 1, otherwise return x*factorial(x-1)
    je if           #je : %rdi == 1

    jmp else

if:                 #return 1
    movq $1, %rax
    jmp factend

else:               #return x*factorial(x-1)
    pushq %rdi      #Save x
    subq $1,%rdi    #Calculate x-1

    call factorial  #Calculate factorial from x-1
    popq %rdi       #Get rdi value before decrement
    mulq %rdi       #Multiply with rax, rax is either 1, or result of previous multiplication

    jmp factend     #End this subroutine, continue with previous 

factend:
    #End of subroutine
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

This implementation doesn't stop, however. I get a segmentation fault, which is caused by a stack overflow. The `if` block is never executed, and the subroutine is stuck in a loop with the `else` code. If I follow my implementation step by step and write down the values of registers and the stack, I don't seem to run in to a problem. What might cause this?

**EDIT**
How I retrieve the input value:

```
formatinput: .asciz "%d"

#Get input from terminal
subq $8, %rsp
leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
movq $0, %rax
movq $formatinput, %rdi
call scanf

#Calculate factorial of input value
movq -8(%rbp), %rdi
movq $1, %rax
call factorial
```

Another **EDIT**

My complete code:

```
#Define main
.global main

.global inout

#Define string to be printed
formatinput: .asciz "%d"
formatoutput: .asciz "%d\n"

str:    .asciz "Assignment %d"


main:


#Start of program   
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    #Print statement
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $4, %rsi
    movq $str, %rdi
    call printf

    call inout

end:
    #Exit program with code 0, no errors
    movq $0, %rdi
    call exit

#inout subroutine
inout:  
    #Start of subroutine
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    #Get input from terminal
    subq $8, %rsp
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $formatinput, %rdi
    call scanf

    #Calculate factorial of input value
    movq -8(%rbp), %rdi
    movq $1, %rax
    call factorial
    movq %rax, -8(%rbp)

    #Print result
    movq $0, %rax
    movq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $formatoutput, %rdi
    call printf

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret

#factorial subroutine
# int factorial(int x){
#   if(x == 1){
#       return 1;
#   }else{
#       return x*factorial(x-1);
#   }
# }

factorial:  
    #Start of subroutine
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp 

    cmpq $1, %rdi       #If rdi == 1, return 1, otherwise return x*factorial(x-1)
    jg if           #jg : %rdi > $1

    jmp else

if:             #return 1
    movq $1, %rax
    jmp factend

else:               #return x*factorial(x-1)
    pushq %rdi      #Save x
    subq $1,%rdi        #Calculate x-1

    call factorial      #Calculate factorial from x-1
    popq %rdi       #Get rdi value before decrement
    mulq %rdi       #Multiply with rax, rax is either 1, or result of previous multiplication

    jmp factend     #End this subroutine, continue with previous 

factend:
    #End of subroutine
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret

#print test subroutine
print:
    #Start of subroutine
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    pushq %rdi
    pushq %rsi
    pushq %rax

    movq $0, %rax
    movq %rdi, %rsi
    movq $formatoutput, %rdi
    call printf

    popq %rsi
    popq %rdi
    popq %rax

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Works fine here. What input did you try and how do you invoke it?

Comment: @Jester I have inputted several different positive integers. I'll edit my post with my input code.

Comment: I don't see any problem, and even that works. Assuming you also have a proper ending after `call factorial`.

Comment: You're using 64-bit integers, while your c-code uses `int`, which is *usually* 32-bit. So your `scanf()` doesn't touch the upper 32 bits of the value you load into `%rdi` to pass to `factorial()`.

Comment: @EOF You're right, it's just pseudocode though. I don't have c-code somewhere that uses this assembly, so I don't think that's a problem. However, since it is a good catch, what variable type should I use in the pseudocode?

Comment: @Jester Updated my post with my complete code

Comment: The point is this: after the `scanf()`, the upper 32-bits `(%rbp-4)` are uninitialized (whatever they were before the `scanf()`). You load them into `%rdi`, and `factorial()` uses *all of* `%rdi`. You may *think* you entered `1`, but `factorial()` thinks you entered something like `18612532834992129`, which *will* blow the stack.

Comment: @EOF So how could I 'clear' the rest of `%rdi`, before I move the value in it? Move 0 in it I guess.

Comment: Yes, you could either replace the `movq -8(%rbp), %rdi` after `scanf()` with `movl -8(%rbp), %edi`, or change the `scanf()`-format specifier from `%d` to `%ld`.

Comment: @EOF If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it, since it now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using 64-bit integers, while your c-code uses `int`, which is usually 32-bit. So your `scanf("%d")` doesn't touch the upper 32 bits of the value you load into `%rdi` to pass to `factorial()`.
Whatever was in those upper bits before the `scanf()` is now interpreted as part of the number you pass, so instead of an input like `1`, `factorial()` interprets it as something like `18612532834992129`, which causes stack overflow.

You could either replace the `movq -8(%rbp), %rdi` after scanf() `with movl -8(%rbp), %edi`, or change the `scanf()`-format specifier from `%d` to `%ld`.

The `movl`-variant shows an interesting tidbit about x86-64: Using a 32-bit operation implicitly clears the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register (the exception being `xchg %eax, %eax`, since this one is the canonical `nop`).